# Integrating Pidgin with Online Accounts

Tags: upgrade, empathy, pidgin, online-accounts

After upgrading from 12.04 LTS to 12.10, Pidgin does not show in the message icon anymore in the tray. I found that the upgrade enabled Empathy with a very old bunch of accounts. I would like to integrate Pidgin with the new Online Accounts functionality instead.

For a temporary solution I just set the tray icon whitlisting to all so Pidgin has it's own, advanced icon. `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"`

That does not integrate it yet though. Is there any reasonable way to do this? Like a Pidgin plugin or PPA that does this with a branched off version?